Tiled matrix multiplication on A100-SXM4-80GB
I am reading matrix-multiplication background user guide by Nvidia.
I am confused by the statement as follows:

A is a M x K matrix, B is a K X N matrix, and C is M x N matrix.
If I understand tiled matrix correctly, C is tiled into multiple submatrices, and the submatrix will be calculated by certain row and col of A and B, respectively.
The problem is, since M = 6912, N = 2048, C will be tiled into (6912 x 2048) / (256 x 128) = 432 submatrix, while an A100-SXM-80GB only has 108 SMs.
That means it needs one SM to handle four tiles.
What's more, in the Wave Quantization chapter, it says that:

An NVIDIA A100 GPU has 108 SMs; in the particular case of 256x128 thread block tiles, it can execute one thread block per SM, leading to a wave size of 108 tiles that can execute simultaneously.

But A100 only has 2048 maximum threads per SM, which is far more smaller than 256 x 128?
These two questions may be quite dumb, but I wish someone can help to enlight me.
Here are my information sources:
Nvidia matrix performance guide
A100 GPU architecture

"That means it needs one SM to handle four tiles." This is not a problem. Reusing tiles tends to be good performance wise if tiles can lie in the cache. If there is one tile per block, this means multiple block par SM which is also better performance wise (1 block is often not enough to saturate a SM due to common latency issues).

"which is far more smaller than 256 x 128" This is not a problem either. You seems to assume each thread has to compute only one item which is not true. Threads can compute multiple items thanks to a loop in the kernel. This loops can be unrolled for petter performance in some cases. Thread coarsening is a key optimization for threads not to reload too much data and keep things compute-bound as much as possible. This might use more registers and even results in a low occupancy while still resulting in higher performance (since occupancy is not the only way to increase performance).

Sorry for the late reply. I do asume each thread has to compute only one item in the result. I understand that it is common for a SM to execute multiple blocks for performance, but back then I did not recall that.
Thank you for your explanation.
